# macro controlled DEBUG

Tags: c++, macros

Here is my code:

macro1.h

```
#ifndef NO_DEBUG
#define DEBUG(arg) cout<<endl<<arg<<endl
#else
#define DEBUG(arg)
#endif
```

macro1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "macro1.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<endl<<"start"<<endl;
  DEBUG("debug line 1");
  #undef NO_DEBUG
  DEBUG("debug line 2");
  #define NO_DEBUG
  DEBUG("debug line 3");
  cout<<endl<<"end"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compile/run it like this:

Compile + Run 1:

```
$ g++ macro1.cpp

$ ./a.out

start

debug line 1

debug line 2

debug line 3

end
$
```

Compile + Run 2:

```
$ g++ macro1.cpp -DNO_DEBUG

$ ./a.out

start

end
$
```

But that is not what I expected, 
In the first run since NO_DEBUG is not defined it had to print:

```
start

debug line 1

debug line 2

end
```

In second run, we are defining macro through command line so it had to print:

```
start

debug line 2

end
```

So can some one please tell me what is going on here?

I am using only pre-processing features so It should work right?.

Comment: Only the macros defined at the point of the `#include "macro1.h"` matter.

Comment: But the content of that .h file can be copy pasted inside the .cpp file also, and pre-processing of .cpp still needed to be done, right? so why only till `#include "macro1.h"` would matter?

Comment: The preprocessor is dumber than you think. It just does the includes, then walks the file from top to bottom. Look at the state of your `.cpp` after the `#include "macro1.h"` and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: I can see the pre-processor did not care about the line:
`#undef NO_DEBUG`
and
`#define NO_DEBUG`
Its weird, then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Again, the preprocessor just walks the file from top to bottom. After the includes, it defines `DEBUG` depending on the value of `NO_DEBUG` and then it's done with that `#define`. It will not go back because `NO_DEBUG` changes later. If you really want to do this with the preprocessor, you need a new `#define DEBUG ...` every time you want to change `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are misunderstanding how the preprocessor works. Here is a good, quick tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

As for your particular problem: the DEBUG macro is only defined once based on the NO_DEBUG macro definition. Once the preprocessor decides which definition to use, you can no longer change the definition of the DEBUG macro. You are trying to use the #unset/#defines to accomplish this but as @Baum mit Augen pointed out, the preprocessor is just a text replacement engine and very "dumb". It doesn't do anything fancy other than replace text.

So by the time you get to your actual DEBUG macros being used, they only have one definition based on NO_DEBUG and you will either get everything printing or nothing printing, as you saw.